# how to open the phone (GPRS) by C# code?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

In Windows-Mobile, how to open the phone? (that will be enable)

Comment: You need to better define what you mean by "open".  Do you want to open a data communication connection?  Do you want voice?  Do you simply mean the default dialer app?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean turn the WWAN radio on and off, you can use TAPI or the Wireless Device Management API.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/RadioPower.aspx

If you're looking for something else, can you be more specific?

-PaulH